# Table is not created in event mysql

Tags: mysql

This query can create event but the table is not created!

```
delimiter ;;
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `test_event`;;
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `test_event` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 minute
    starts current_timestamp()
    ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
    COMMENT 'test report'
    DO  BEGIN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
         CREATE TABLE test (name VARCHAR(20), owner VARCHAR(20),
     species VARCHAR(20), sex CHAR(1), birth DATE, death DATE);
    END;
```

any idea?

Comment: This might help you: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/

Answer (score 0):

Your event scheduler is correct. First check it's status

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'event_scheduler'
```

By default Event Scheduler status has been set to DISABLED. To enable your event scheduler:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Comment: `event_scheduler` is ON but still does't create expected table

Comment: I execute your query and it created table in my local database. Are you root user

Comment: if you are [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15241596/1379347)